# Failed to update HTC Desire S to latest firmware with Android 2.3.5

Tags: updates, htc-desire-s

My phone configuration is:

- Model HTC Desire S
- Android 2.3.3
- HTC Sense 2.1
- Build number 1.47.401.4

Today I've got notification that an update is available for my phone with:

- HTC Sence 3.0
- Android 2.3.5

I've downloaded the update and started it. My phone rebooted, then for several seconds I saw green icon showing that update is going. After that I've received the red exclamation mark icon. I've triggered the recover console and saw the following:

```
Finding update package...
Opening update package...
Verifying update package...
Installing update...
Copying fotaBoot to /data/system for customize reload...
Verifying current system...
assert failed: apply_patch_check ("/system/app/EReader.apk", "5f3c2be955e09...", "c4071fc9ffc21...")
E:Error in /sdcard/download/OTA_Saga_S_HTC_Europe_2.10.401.8-1.47.401.4_release_225210fmxlt12djw1sr7y5.zip
(Status 7)
Installation aborted.
```

As far as I understood from the log, the CRC failed for the EReader.apk. Does that mean that the updated downloaded incorrectly? Or maybe there are some issues with my phone?

Can someone, please, help me with this issue:

- Should I forget about this update and wait for the next one?
- Is it the bug in the system or in my phone?
- Can I somehow (without rooting the device) overcome the problem and install the update?
- Any other thoughts are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mostly likely the update over the air downloaded the wrong archive, which failed to automatically install. In addition to that I found on several forums that the phone had many broken stuff after such update. Therefore I've decided to update it manually.

I've downloaded the zip archive with latest official firmware, put it on my sdcard, rebooted the phone into recover console. It automatically found my zip archive and the phone was updated. Everything works fine now.

The complete instructions together with latest firmware can be found here (Russian language): http://www.youhtc.ru/forum/showthread.php?p=304305&posted=1#post304305

I've translated them in short below:

- Download the zip archive with RUU_Saga_S_HTC_Europe_2.10.401.8_Radio_20.4801.30. 0822U_3822.10.08.04_M_release_225161_signed.exe from [here](http://narod.ru/disk/32225794001/rom.zip.html)
- Rename the zip archive to **PG88IMG.zip** and put it in the root directory on sd card
- Power off the phone
- Press volume-down button and then power button.
- The recovery console will pop up. The phone will automatically find the zip file and check it. It will ask you to confirm the update. If you're OK with that, the phone will be updated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe your downloaded update file is broken somehow.

Further notice:!! manual operations always have the risk to brick your phone. So be careful, and remember I take no responsibility.

You can manually update with rom update utility (RUU). RUU is a PC program that updates your phone through usb connection.

You should backup all your information first.

And you can find the released ruu list here http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1002506 
As of know, latest seems to be RUU_Saga_S_HTC_Europe_2.10.401.8

Comment: Thanks for reply. Do I need to root my phone or make any other changes to it to manually update with RUU?

Comment: Sorry for the late comment, you don't have to root your phone. Here is another post about what you are looking for: http://www.androidauthority.com/how-to-update-your-htc-desire-s-to-android-2-3-5-gingerbread-37319/